# android cannot open my app

Tags: java, android

I have built the .apk for a little application I wrote for android. On the installation finished screen the "Open" option is grayed out and can not be chosen. After when I search the device for the application no icon appears, if I check installed apps it is there but still cannot be opened. I believe this is a problem with the androidmanifest.xml. I have very little experience with the androidmanifest and mostly just work with java.

```
<application

    android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
          <category android:name="andriod.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>







        </activity>





</application>
```

Above is my manifest, I understand my manifest probably has many errors so thank you for your help and patients in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default launcher intent:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I edited my manifest to your specifications and had the same issue. The application installed but could not be opened nor did the icon to launch appear. Do you have any thoughts as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Of course, I have changed the previous code in the question to be my current manifest.

Comment: you have a typo: <category android:name="**andriod**.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

Comment: OK thank you for showing me this, I'm sad to say I missed this completely.

Answer (score 2):

is this a typo ?

```
intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MainActivity"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

it should be like this

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your intent-filter is wrong, that's the reason why android won't create an icon. Just have a quick Google lookup or create a new project and copy the intent-filter out of the Manifest.